# How to handle an object array of Object Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have this code:

```
Object [] array=new Object array [5];
array[0]= new Object[3];
array[1]=new Object [10];
array[2]=new Object [7];
...
```

How can I access the 5th element of array[1].
If it was a 2D array I would say:

```
Object o=array [1][5];
```

but I don't want 2D array because I don't want to waste memory since the size varies from array to array.

It would be great if someone could answer me this question..

Btw I don't want to use vectors etc...

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? If you did, you wouldn't have asked that.

Comment: Create two dimensional array to hold array[array]  http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```
//This creates a 5 by ? array
Object[][] array = new Object[5][];

array[0] = new Object[3];
array[1] = new Object[10];
array[2] = new Object[7];
....
```

edit (thanks to the commenters) :

`array` is an array of arrays. Each element in `array` refers to an array of Objects. 
The memory is not wasted on having more elements than needed.

It will look like this

```
[a00][a01][a02]
[a10][a11][a12][a13][a14][a15][a16][a17][a18][a19]
[a20][a21][a22][a23][a24][a25][a12]
```

If you now would like to access the 6th element of the 2nd array you would do this:

```
Object myObj = array[1][5];
```

Comment: And additionally you can use `Object o=array [1][5];` to access elements.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that a 2D array *is* an array of arrays.

Comment: Glad that I could help. If it solves your problem, can you accept the answer?